# Finding first and second derivative of an function with an absolute value

Tags: calculus, derivatives, graphing-functions, absolute-value

Given the equation $f(x)= |x^2-9|$ where $-4\le x\le 5$, I must find the extremes, as well as the concavities.

This I know how to do.

The issue is I'm unfamiliar on how to find the first and second derivative of the given function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Typically, absolute value functions require a piecewise definition, so you might look at that and go from there.

Comment: $f(x)=\pm (x^2-9)$, and for extremas ($f'(x)=0$) modulus doesn't matter. Or, you can find extremas of $f^2(x)=(x^2-9)^2$

Comment: @TerraHyde You mean the definition that when x>0 f(x)=|x2−9| but when x<0  f(x)=-|x2−9| or am I going into the wrong direction?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza why doesn't it matter? There's an interval restriction so there's going to be a local max and local min somewhere.

Comment: @ally463, I mean  if $f(x)=|g(x)|$, then finding extremas of $f(x)$ equivalent to finding extremas of $g(x)$ and finding roots of $f(x)$; formally, $f'(x)=\frac{g(x)}{|g(x)|} g'(x)$, but $g(x)/|g(x)|=\pm 1$; so, $f'(x)=0\implies g'(x)=0$. And we should check case $g(x)=0$ separately

Comment: @ally463 The definition moves with this one out to $x=\pm3$ because those are the places the function would cross the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f(x)$ is

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2-9,&\text{for}\,\,|x|\ge 3\\\\
9-x^2,&\text{for}\,\,|x|\le 3&
\end{cases}$$

Thus, the derivative $f'(x)$ is

$$f'(x)=
\begin{cases}
2x,&\text{for}\,\,|x|\ge 3\\\\
-2x,&\text{for}\,\,|x|\le 3
\end{cases}$$

Both the derivative from the left and right are zero at $x=0$ and so this is a local extremum. To check to see if this is a local maximum or a local minimum we can either take a second derivative (which is $-2<0\implies \text{a local maximum}$) or observe that the derivative decreases to the right of $x=0$ and increases to the left (which implies a local maximum).

Thus, the other possible critical points are at the endpoints of the interval $[-4,5]$ or at $x=\pm 3$. The task then is to test these points, compare and determine the absolute extrema.

---

**NOTE:**

Aside, it might be of interest to note that inasmuch as

$$\frac{d|x|}{dx}=\frac{x}{|x|}$$

for $x\ne0$, then

$$\frac{d|f(x)|}{dx}=f'(x)\,\left(\frac{f(x)}{|f(x)|}\right)$$

for $f(x)\ne 0$

Comment: I have attempted using this however the procedure is long and prone to error when finding the second derivative. Is there any other way to find the second?
However, that means the first derivative is f'(x)=x2−9/|x2−9|. For critical points, can you ever set the denominator to 0 and solve for x normally, ignoring the fact it's absolute? 
ex |x2−9| =0 --> x2−9=0 --> x=+3,-3

Comment: @ally463 I edited to make clearer a path forward.  But, using the "formula," one finds that $$\frac{d|x^2-9|}{dx}=2x\frac{x^2-9}{|x^2-9|}$$which equals to $2x$ when $x^2-9$ is positive (i.e., $|x|>3$) and is negative otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

For $x>0$,

$$|x|=x,\ |x|'=1,\ |x|''=0.$$

For $x<0$,

$$|x|=-x,\ |x|'=-1,\ |x|''=0.$$

For $x=0$, neither $|x|'$ nor $|x|''$ are defined.

You can summarize with

$$\text{for }x\ne0,\ |x|'=\text{sign}(x),\ |x|''=0.$$

---

Let us solve the exercise:

For $x^2-9\ne0$,

$$f'(x)=2x\text{ sign}(x^2-9)$$

has a zero at $x=0$, and changes sign at $x=\pm3$.

$$-\infty\searrow-3\nearrow0\searrow3\nearrow\infty$$

As
$$f''(x)=2\text{ sign}(x^2-9)$$
the concavities go like

$$-\infty\smile-3\frown3\smile\infty.$$

$x=0$ is a maximum, and due to the discontinuity of the derivative, $x=\pm3$ are angular points.